# React Native: Send component state to other component using Tab Navigator

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I have a component to add todos **AddTodo** which works fine and update the state with my added todos and I have a component **TodoItems** to display the todos in `<FlatList/>`. I'm using [React Native Tab Navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab) to switch between components but I'm not sure how to send the state `this.state.todos` from **AddTodo** component to **TodoItems** component.

I have been researching but couldn't find a solution in Tab Navigator but there are plenty of solutions for Stack Navigator.

---

**Component AddTodo**

```
export default class AddTodo extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           todoText: null,
           todos: []
       }
    }

    onAdd = () => {
        if (this.state.todoText) {
            this.state.todos.push({'todoItem': this.state.todoText});
            this.setState({todos: this.state.todos});
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
             <View>
                  <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => {
                       this.setState({todoText: text});
                  }} />
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                       this.onAdd;
                  }}>
             </View>
        );
    }

}
```

---

**Component TodoItems**

```
export default class TodoItems extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           todosList: []
       }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                  <FlatList
                      data={this.state.todosList}
                      renderItem={(item, index) => {
                          <Text>{item.todoItem}</Text>
                      }} 
                  />
            </View>
        );
    }

}
```

---

**Component Tabs**

```
import {TabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import AddTodo from "./AddTodo";
import TodoItems from "./TodoItems";

var myTabs = TabNavigator(
    {
    'AddTodo':{screen: AddTodo,},
    'TodoItems':{screen: TodoItems, },
    },
    {
    tabBarPosition: 'top',
    swipeEnabled: false,
    tabBarOptions: {
        labelStyle:{
            fontSize: 13,
            fontWeight: 'bold',

        },
        indicatorStyle: {
            borderBottomColor: '#003E7D',
            borderBottomWidth: 2,
        },
        style:{
            backgroundColor: '#F30076',
            elevation: 0,
        },
    },
});


export default myTabs;
```

Comment: Why are AddTodo and TodoItems separate components?

Comment: Because I want them to be two different screens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I think you have two options:

1. You can use Redux which allows you to globalise your state objects so you can use them all over your app, but it can be rather complicated
   https://redux.js.org/
2. Or you can render TodoItems from within AddTodo:

   ```
   render() {
     return(
        <View>
             <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => {
                  this.setState({todoText: text});
             }} />
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                  this.onAdd;
             }}>
        </View>
        <TodoItems data={this.state.todos} />
     );
   }
   ```

Then you can access that data from within TodoItems:
Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah I saw many were saying to use Redux on similar questions. Are you suggesting that I should not have two tabs instead just one?

Comment: @Omer I think you could have the add functionality and the flatlist on one screen. When the user adds an item, it will appear in the flatlist and they will not need to navigate anywhere else to see this data. The simplest and the neatest is often the best when it comes to users.

Comment: Totally Agree ... I might need to change the design now :/

Comment: BTW I have achieved this with Stack Navigator in another application. Was hoping that Tab Navigation will do the same :(

Comment: @Omer Cool :) If my answer helped in anyway, please mark it as accepted for this question. Hope the Design goes well!

Comment: Yes your answer make sense because I did not found any solution on the internet regarding this. Let's hope they **(react-native team)** will add this feature in the near future :)

Comment: @Omer Yes it would be a nice addition!

Comment: I'm using `<FlatList />` but its not updating ... However I can populate the added todos by `.map()` any idea? Do you want me to create a new question?

Comment: @Omer Make sure both are using state. Make sure also that the flatlist is using state as its data.

Comment: @Omer If you want to create another question do, but when the user is adding the item, make sure you are updating the data and setting it in state.  Then the data in the Flatlist should be this.state.myData or whatever you call it

Comment: Actually figure it out by adding `extraData` in **<FlatList />**

Comment: @Omer Oh yes that as well! Good Stuff :)

Comment: thanks for your help. Everything's pull together nicely and and app is looking great now :)

Comment: @Omer No bother! Glad to help